# I set up new clan but accidentally left it. No other players in the clan yet. Can I recover it?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I'm trying to help my grandson who is new to Clash of Clans. He set up a new clan, invited his friends to join, but before anyone joined, he accidentally left the clan and now can't find it.

Does it still exist, and if so, how can he recover it?  He is playing on iPad mini. Any assistance greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Since it is a new clan, there will not be much clan XP and perks assosiated with it, which would be the main reason of keeping it. You can just create a new clan with the same name.

Answer (score 4):

It does still exist. But you can't get back in the clan. You must create a new clan.